# How do I enable the "Port Settings" tab for a Usb Serial Port device?

Tags: windows, driver, usbserial

I am maintaining software for a usb peripheral that comes up as a serial port on Windows Device Manager.

The .inf file just specifies the standard usbser.sys driver.

Most such devices have a "Port Settings" tab under properties where the serial port assignment for the device can be changed - which is what I want to be able to do for this device I am maintaining.

How can I enable the "Port Settings" tab?

I tried adding an 'AddService' directive for serenum.sys to my .inf file (on the basis that all the devices that do have Ports Settings tab have this driver) but that did not work. But as serenum.sys did not come up under the "Driver" tab under Driver Details maybe I didn't add that correctly.

Comment: Will you be solving it with programming?

Comment: Happily I have found a solution. Which I will post after the 8hr limit for newbies. @Ignacio. Is writing .inf file programming? I'd say yes but others may disagree.

Comment: Lemme shake the magic 8 ball... it says...... on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inf file does the business:

http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/cdc_acm_class.inf

This line seems to be the key to enabling the Port Settings tab.

`HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"msports.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"`

but that alone is not enough - contrary to this link  http://www.digital-kaos.co.uk/forums/f34/how-change-com-port-settings-using-usb-serial-adapter-1926/ (scroll down to the *second* post).

The first link above also has some other goodness such as using `Include=mdmcpq.inf`, as MS recommends, rather that referencing usbser.sys directly.

Time for some coff-ay!

EDIT: Save yourself the hassle a friend of mine had and don't rename 'FakeModemCopyFileSection' in the example cdc_acm_class.inf above; It seems 'FakeModemCopyFileSection' is a well-known section name (imported from mdmcpq.inf ?).

Comment: Just adding `HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"msports.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"` was what I needed, Thanks!